# How can I implement a more complex promise chain in javascript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I try to implement a more complex promise chain.
Flow and dependencies:

- Start A, B and D
- Start C when A and B are done
- Start E when C and D are done

Here the simulation code:

```
function test_p(name, sec) {
    console.log(Date.now()-start,'Started ', name, " Sec: ", sec);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(Date.now()-start,'Resolved ', name, " Sec: ", sec);
            resolve(10);
        }, sec * 1000);
    });
}
start = Date.now(); 
p1 = test_p("A", 2)
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start, result); return result });
p2 = test_p("B", 5)
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start,result); return result });
pp1 = Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start,"p1-p2 startet"); return result })
    .then(() => { console.log(Date.now()-start,"p1-p2 done ") })
    .then(() => {
        p3 = test_p("C", 5)
            .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now() - start, result); return result })
    });    
p4 = test_p("D", 7)
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start,result); return result });
pp2 = Promise.all([pp1, p3, p4])
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start,"pp1-p4 startet"); return result });
```

> This is the console protocol:  0 'Started ' 'A' ' Sec: ' 2 VM10447:2 2
> 'Started ' 'B' ' Sec: ' 5 VM10447:2 2 'Started ' 'D' ' Sec: ' 7
> Promise {} VM10447:5 2001 'Resolved ' 'A' ' Sec: ' 2
> VM10489:3 2001 10 VM10447:5 5003 'Resolved ' 'B' ' Sec: ' 5 VM10489:5
> 5003 10 VM10489:7 5003 'p1-p2 startet' VM10489:8 5003 'p1-p2 done '
> VM10447:2 5003 'Started ' 'C' ' Sec: ' 5 VM10447:5 7002 'Resolved '
> 'D' ' Sec: ' 7 VM10489:14 7003 10 VM10489:16 7003 'pp1-p4 startet'
> VM10447:5 10004 'Resolved ' 'C' ' Sec: ' 5 VM10489:11 10004 10

I wanted the second Promise.all to fire after C resolved around 10000 msec

Comment: you could create a working code snippet right inside your question

Comment: Can you provide a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Any logging you included for debugging most likely won't help us debug. Only include what is necessary in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your hint - I have to look up how to do that.

Comment: The code I included will run when copied into chrome debugging console or codepen -
Pls let me know what I can add Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue your current code is that the last `.then()` call in `pp1` doesn't return `p3`. As a result, you start timer C, but you never make it a dependency of `pp1`. So to fix it, simply return `p3` inside that `.then()`, like so:

```js
pp1 = Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now()-start,"p1-p2 startet"); return result })
    .then(() => { console.log(Date.now()-start,"p1-p2 done ") })
    .then(() => {
        p3 = test_p("C", 5)
            .then((result) => { console.log(Date.now() - start, result); return result })
        return p3;
    });
```

However, your code overall can be immensely simplified and improved for readability like so:

```js
const start = Date.now();

async function delay(name, timeInSec) {
    return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, timeInSec * 1000)).then(() =>
        console.log(name, Date.now() - start)
    );
}

console.log("start:", start);
const A = delay("A", 2);
const B = delay("B", 5);
const D = delay("D", 7);

const ABC = Promise.all([A, B]).then(() => delay("C", 5));

const CDE = Promise.all([ABC, D]).then(() => delay("E", 2));
```

Comment: Many thanks,, it was the return p3 I was missing. I prefer the  ".then" construct because it passes the return values vs. the async/await.

Comment: @MichaelThum `then` is interchangeable with `async..await`. how are you perceiving them as different?